# how to bring drop down menu infront of slider

Tags: html, css, slider, navbar

hi  i am having provlems with my  drop down menu  on my index page, the drop down items are hidden below my image slider which is directly below my nav bar, i would like to be able to see the drop down menu items, any help would be greatly appreciated 
thank you very much;

**here is my html for the nav bar:**

```
<div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>


        <li class=""><a href="#">sports news</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">headlines</a></li>

             <li><a href="#">when an where</a></li>
             <li><a href="">rewind</a></li>
             <li><a href="">manager of the week </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="about"><a class="active" href="#">music</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">events</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News #2@@@</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">events</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
```

**and here is my css:**

```
/*
jmc
*/

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #4d4638;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.7em; 
    background: url(images/tooplate_body.jpg);
    background-color: #c2b8a1;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top    
}

a, a:link, a:visited { color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

.orange {
    color: #FC0;
}

.green {
    color: #CF6;
}

p { margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 0; }
img { border: none; }
em { color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: #000; font-weight: normal; }
h1 { font-size: 34px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 5px 0 }
h2 { font-size: 28px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 5px 0; }
h3 { font-size: 24px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;  }
h6 { font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 5px; padding: 0; }

.cleaner { clear: both }
.h10 { height: 10px }
.h20 { height: 20px }
.h30 { height: 30px }
.h40 { height: 40px }
.h50 { height: 50px }
.h60 { height: 60px }

a.more { 
    clear: both; 
    display: block; 
    width: 87px; 
    height: 31px; 
    padding-right: 15px; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #000; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: url(images/tooplate_btn.png); 
}

a.more:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #960; 
}

.float_l { float: left }
.float_r { float: right }

.tooplate_margin { margin: 10px; }

.image_wrapper { 
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid #cac2b1; 
    background: #b5ac98; 
    padding: 4px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

.image_fl { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 3px 15px 0 0; 
}

.image_fr { 
    float: right; 
    margin: 3px 0 0 15px; 
}

.tooplate_list { 
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
}

.tooplate_list li { 
    color:#000; 
    margin: 0 0 5px 0; 
    padding: 0 0 0 25px; 
    background: url(images/tooplate_list.png) no-repeat scroll 0 5px;  
}

.tooplate_list li a { 
    color: #000; 
    font-weight: normal; 
}

.tooplate_list li a:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

#tooplate_header {
    width: 960px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#site_title { 
    float: left; 
}

#site_title h1 { 
    margin: 30px 0 0 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

#site_title h1 a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 278px; 
    height: 50px; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-indent: -10000px; 
    background: url(images/tooplate_logo.png) no-repeat; 
}

/* menu */
#tooplate_menu {
    float: right;
    width: 632px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: url(images/tooplate_menu.png)
}

#tooplate_menu ul {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#tooplate_menu ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

#tooplate_menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 116px;
    padding: 9px 4px 9px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cec8ba;
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: url(images/tooplate_menu_divider.png) center right no-repeat
}

#tooplate_menu ul li a:hover, #tooplate_menu ul li .current { 
    color: #fff; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #3d3728;  
}

#tooplate_menu ul .last { 
    background: none; 
}

#search_box { 
    float: right; 
    margin: 12px 0 0 0; 
    width: 170px; 
    height: 27px; 
    background: url(images/tooplate_search.png) no-repeat; 
}

#search_box form { 
    clear: both; 
    width: 170px; 
    height: 26px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
} 

#searchfield { 
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    height: 16px; 
    width: 130px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #ccc; 
    line-height: 0; 
    background: none; 
    border: none; 
} 

#searchbutton { 
    float: right; 
    display: block; 
    height: 26px; 
    width: 30px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none; 
    border: none; 
}

/* end of menu */

/* slider */

#tooplate_middle { 
    clear: both;
    width: 940px;
    height: 307px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/tooplate_middle_home.png) no-repeat
}

#tooplate_middle_subpage { 
    clear: both;
    width: 820px;
    height: 207px;
    padding: 60px 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background: url(images/tooplate_middle_subpage.png) no-repeat;
}

#tooplate_middle_subpage h2 { 
    font-size: 48px; 
    color: #000; 
}

#tooplate_middle_subpage p { 
    font-size: 18px; 
    color: #000; 
    line-height: 30px; 
}

#tooplate_middle_subpage a { 
    color: #507921; 
    font-weight: normal; 
}

#slider {
    float: right;
    width: 940px;
    height: 300px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* end of slider */

#tooplate_main {
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col_w960 { width: 960px; margin-bottom: 40px }
.col_w600 { width: 600px }
.col_w450 { width: 450px }
.col_w300 { width: 300px }
.col_allw300 { width: 300px; float: left; margin-right: 30px }
.col_last { margin: 0 }
.col_w960_last { margin: 0; background: none; }
.col_last { margin: 0; }

.wwd_box { clear: both; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px }
.wwd_box img { float: left; width: 80px; margin-right: 30px }
.wwd_box h3 { font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0 }
.wwd_box h3 a { color: #507921; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal }
.wwd_box p { margin-bottom: 30px; }

.lp_box { float: left; width: 300px; margin-right: 30px }
.lp_box h6 { font-weight: bold; color: #507921 }
.lp_box_last { margin: 0 }
.lp_box img { border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: 4px }

#cp_contact_form { 
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0; 
    width: 412px; 
}

#cp_contact_form form { 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}

#cp_contact_form form .input_field { 
    width: 400px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;  
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#cp_contact_form form label { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100px; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
}

#cp_contact_form form textarea { 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 160px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#cp_contact_form form .submit_btn { 
    margin: 5px 0px;
    padding: 5px 14px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;  
}

#map {
    margin: 10px;
}

#map img { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid #d9d3c5; 
    background: #b5ac98; 
    padding: 7px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.news_box { 
    clear: both; 
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
    padding-bottom: 30px; 
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #333; 
}

.news_box h2 { 
    font-size: 20px; 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.news_box p.date { 
    color: #000; 
}

.news_box img { 
    float: left; 
    padding: 4px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    margin-right: 30px; 
}

.news_box a.more { 
    clear:none; 
    float: right; 
}

.sb_lp_box { 
    clear: both; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.sb_lp_box img { 
    border: 1px solid #cac2b1; 
    background: #b5ac98; 
    padding: 8px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.post_box { 
    clear: both; 
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}

.post_box h2 { 
    font-size: 20px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.post_box p.post_meta { 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.post_box p span.cat a { 
    color: #507921; 
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.post_box img { 
    width: 550px; 
    height: 160px; 
    border: 1px solid #cac2b1; 
    background: #b5ac98; 
    padding: 8px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.post_box a.more { 
    float: left; 
}

.lbe_box { 
    clear: both; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.lbe_box h3 { 
    font-size: 16px; 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.lbe_box h3 a { 
    color: #507921; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
}

.lbe_box h3 a span { 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #507921; 
}

.lbe_box p { 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.lbe_box p.date { 
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-weight: 700; 
    color: #507921; 
}

#gallery { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

#gallery ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#gallery ul li { 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 281px; 
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0; 
    padding: 8px; 
    border: 1px solid #d0c9b8; 
    background: #b6ac97; 
}

#gallery ul .third { 
    margin: 0 0 30px 0; 
}

#gallery ul li a img { 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

#tooplate_footer_wrapper {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background: #a19882;
    border-top: 10px solid #d0c8b4;
}

#tooplate_footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    background:  url(images/tooplate_footer.jpg) top center no-repeat
}

#tooplate_cr a { 
    color: #5fa008; 
    font-weight: normal;


}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}

/*******************************************
   Style menu for larger screens

   Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
   or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
    }


    #nav ul {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

thanks again;

Comment: Can you provide html that includes the image slider? It looks like this works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/v8f3bc7r/

Comment: <div id="slider">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slideshow/01.jpg" alt="slideshow 01" title="wow" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slideshow/02.jpg" alt="slideshow 02" title="wow" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slideshow/03.jpg" alt="slideshow 03" title="wow" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slideshow/04.jpg" alt="slideshow 04" title="wow" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slideshow/05.jpg" alt="slideshow 05" title="wow" /></a>
    </div>

Comment: Are you using a tool for the slider? If you have links or scripts in your html we'll need them to figure out what is happening. As straight html can't reproduce what you describe. http://jsfiddle.net/v8f3bc7r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from the snippet provided, my best guess would be to add:

```
position:relative;
```

to your:

```
#nav ul{
    z-index:9999;
}
```

**HOWEVER** I cannot see div id="nav" in your html! If you have just not included it in your snippet, that's fine, but if this is also an error and you mean to assign that css to div class="nav", then try changing that whole block to:

```
.nav ul{
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

One final note to remember, assign z-index to elements that ALSO have a position set (be it relative or absolute etc) - as far as i'm aware, z-index doesn't work unless the block has a position attribute set to it also.

Hope this works for you.